# Subscribing to KeyUp event of TextBox with Rx?

Tags: .net, winforms, system.reactive

All of the examples I've seen contain code that looks something like this:

```
Dim eventAsObservable = Observable.FromEvent(Of KeyEventArgs)(Me.txtSearch, "KeyUp")
```

However, that raises an error stating that the FromEvent method is expecting an Action that accepts KeyEventArgs.

Has the syntax for subscribing to these types of events changed?

Answer (score 3):

You have to use [Observable.FromEventPattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.observable.fromeventpattern%28v=vs.103%29.aspx):

```
var observable = Observable.FromEventPattern<KeyEventArgs>(this.txt, "KeyUp");
observable.Subscribe(x => Console.Write(x.EventArgs.Key));
```